# How to check if user has clicked to share and is it allowed to do?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using the share intent to allow users to share their app anywhere they like. The app is free and uses ads. I'd like to make it so that if user shares my app a certain amount of times, the ads get removed (something like buying a paid app that removes ads).

My First question is: Is this allowed? I've read Facebook platform policy and they say you should not incentivize users to share something in order to get something. And in this case I'm not really incentivizing them, I simply offer them to share and then ads will be removed, same as if they bought a paid app. Note: Users can share on anything, WhatsApp and so on...

Second, I Know you cannot check if user has just gone to WhatsApp and clicked back or really shared, so I just want to check if user has clicked where to share using share intent (once share intent was opened, did he click to share on WhatsApp for example or just clicked back). How can I do that?

This is my share intent code:

```
String appPackageName = getPackageName();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
```

Comment: It's hard(impossible?) to know what a user did while in another app unless that app sends a signal back letting you know.

Comment: I know. That's what I've written. Check my second question. "I know you cannot check if user has just gone to WhatsApp and clicked back or really shared". Maybe I phrased it badly. I want to check, once that app sends the share intent and when share dialog is opened, if user clicked to enter some other app to share (actually uses the share intent) or if he just closed the share intent dialog.